# How to approximate the entropy of convoluted Normal Inverse Wishart distribution?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo, entropy, inverse-wishart

I am struggling with the (Monte Carlo) approximation of the entropy of convoluted Normal Inverse Wishart distribution. If anyone knows how to do it, I would like to borrow your wisdom. The following is a more concrete question.

Suppose, there are two NIW distributions,

$$
1. p(\mu_a, \Sigma_a) = NIW(\mu_1, \lambda_1, \Psi_1, \nu_1) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_a|\mu_1, \frac{1}{\lambda_1}\Sigma_a)\mathcal{W}^{-1}(\Sigma_a|\Psi_1, \nu_1) \\
2. p(\mu_b, \Sigma_b) = NIW(\mu_2, \lambda_2, \Psi_2, \nu_2) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_b|\mu_2, \frac{1}{\lambda_2}\Sigma_b)\mathcal{W}^{-1}(\Sigma_b|\Psi_2, \nu_2)
$$
(*Dimensions of $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ are the same) Given these two NIW distributions, I would like to know the entropy of convoluted NIW, which is $H[p(\mu_a + \mu_b, \Sigma_a + \Sigma_b)]$. It seems there is no analytically expression of the convoluted NIW, so I tried to approximate the entropy of it via the Monte Carlo sampling. But, I am not sure what the correct steps to be taken.